# How to convert string to json vb.net

Tags: json, string, vb.net

this is the code i have, dim sline from string to json, i have try it and search on google, but i havent done yet...

please help

```
Dim sURL As String
sURL = TextBox1.Text
Dim wrGETURL As WebRequest
wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
Dim myProxy As New WebProxy("myproxy", 80)
myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = True

wrGETURL.Proxy = myProxy

wrGETURL.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy()
Dim objStream As Stream
objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream()

Dim objReader As New StreamReader(objStream)
Dim sLine As String = ""
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do While Not sLine Is Nothing
    i += 1
    sLine = objReader.ReadLine
    If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, sLine)
    End If
Loop
Dim respon As Array = sLine.ToArray()
Console.ReadLine()
Console.WriteLine(respon("traceNo"))
Console.ReadLine()
```

i want to convert the Dim sline to json, how it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Newtonsoft.JSON is a VERY handy NuGet to easy use JSON in VB.Net.

Seperate your lines into a List(Of Integer, String) (i,sLine) 
and Serialize it with

```
Dim yourJSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourList)
```

Comment: failed to install that package on my visual studio

Comment: If it fails to install just a NuGet, than you should repair your visual studio first

Comment: @Kenzie Which version of Visual Studio are you using?